# How to fetch one tables - every column?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to fetch all data from TABLE_Meals. Every column. So, for instance I'll have 12 meals. I'll mark them as mealsId. For every meal I want different details - description, size, price. I want to retrieve (desc, size, price) for certain meal in ArrayList.

```
// DETAILS TABLE - Column names
private static final String desc = "Description";
private static final String size = "Size";
private static final String price = "Price";
private static final String mealsId = "meals_id";

// COMMON COLUMN NAMES
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";


// CREATE STATEMENT FOR TABLES
private static final String CREATE_DETAILS = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_Details + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + desc + " TEXT," + size + " TEXT,"
        + price + " TEXT," + mealsId + " INTEGER)";

// CREATING DETAILS -??????????????????
public void addDetails(String d, String s, String p, int id)
{
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues(3);
    values.put(desc, d);
    values.put(size, s);
    values.put(price, p);
    values.put(categoryId, id);
    getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_Meals, null, values);
}

 public Cursor getDetails(int id)
{
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_Details + " WHERE " + mealsId + "=" + String.valueOf(id), null);
    return cursor;
}

// FETCH DETAILS
public ArrayList<Details> GetAllDetails(int id)
{
    ArrayList<Details> list = new ArrayList<Details>();
    Cursor cursor =  getDetails(id);
    int i = 0; // Iterator for 'do-while'. While it gets Categories names, it shall catch all the url's from array as well.
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            Details det = new Details();
            det.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
            det.getDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(desc)));
            det.getSize(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(size)));
            det.getPrice(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(price)));

            list.add(det);
            i++;
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())

    {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Error occuring:

```
 det.getDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(desc)));
 det.getSize(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(size)));
 det.getPrice(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(price)));
```

Also, I'm pretty sure ADD DETAILS function is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Please check this [link](http://www.androhub.com/android-sqlite-database/).

Comment: Shouldn't it be mealsId instead of categoryId in addDetails method?

Comment: @AlphaQ and Surender Kumar - didnt help